# Ropsten (Ethereum test network) transactions won't resolve (still pending), using Web3js

Tags: ethereum, web3js

I have some code that interacts with an existing smart contract on Ropsten. I have run it multiple times in the past and had no issue.

I'll post the full code and the two errors that I get when I try some alterations to the code.

```
var Tx = require("ethereumjs-tx");
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3(
  "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/d55489f8ea264a1484c293b05ed7eb85"
);

const abi = [...];
const contractAddress = "0x15E1ff7d97CB0D7C054D19bCF579e3147FC9009b";
const myAccount = "0x59f568176e21EF86017EfED3660625F4397A2ecE";
const privateKey1 = new Buffer(
  "__PrivateKey__",
  "hex"
);

hashValue = "newly updated value";

const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress, {
  from: myAccount
});

web3.eth.getTransactionCount(myAccount, (err, txCount) => {
  //Smart contract data
  const data = contract.methods.setHashValue(hashValue).encodeABI();

  // Build the transaction
  const txObject = {
    nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(1000000),
    gasPrice: 100000,
    data: data,
    from: myAccount,
    to: contractAddress
  };

  // Sign the transaction
  const tx = new Tx(txObject);
  tx.sign(privateKey1);

  const serializedTx = tx.serialize();

  // Broadcast the transaction
  web3.eth
    .sendSignedTransaction("0x" + serializedTx.toString("hex"))
    .on("receipt", console.log);
});
```

If I deploy this code, it creates a transaction that stays pending indefinitely.

If I run it again I get

> Returned error: replacement transaction underpriced

If I alter the code to add to the nonce like this `nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount + 1)` I am returned an error that it is a known transaction (the pending transaction).

Very frustrating is that this code worked fine a few days ago!

I'm wondering if I maybe changed my Web3 module on accident...and the version change broke something. Or is there a problem with Ropsten? Last night it was not showing any blocks or transactions.

The two pending transactions are

0xc57316782bb34608b16c7f5ebd1cfb4404a0c8f1b0d5b3e6db6a2f973c527bc3

0xe0d4c513c03c3dba5e853ac0511ee6cf06be6728ba0e054b703cdc49086aa5f7

Answer (score 0):

I manually replaced the nonce field with the pending nonces, and gave the transaction 20000000000 gas price. This replaced the pending transactions. Suddenly the original code is working again...